# What are examples of tutorials and blogs for beginners to master the cross-lingual information retrieval?

Tags: natural-language-processing, resource-request, information-retrieval

Currently, I am following the [Dan Jurofsky NLP Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQiyVNMpDLKnZYBTUOlSI9mi9wAErFtFm) and [CS 224 Stanford 2019](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rXD5-xhemo&list=PLoROMvodv4rOhcuXMZkNm7j3fVwBBY42z). Can you list tutorials and blogs for beginners to master the cross-lingual information retrieval?